# What is the meaning of the notation $]1, 1[$?

Tags: notation

This may look like a silly question but I am struck in my work with this notation in one of the papers.

What is meant by $]1,1[$ ?

Comment: Probably old fashioned notation for an open interval: $x\in]1,1[$ if and only if $-1<x<1$. Compare with $x\in[1,1]$ if and only if $-1\leq x\leq1$.

Comment: Please use TeX formatting in your question because the title is **unreadable** (I see literally: `] 1, 1[`).

Comment: Why old-fashioned? This is the standard French convention.

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1155799/what-does-it-mean-when-range-is-expressed-between-two

Answer (score 0):

$]a,b[$ is an alternative notation for the open interval that I’d denote by $(a,b)$, i.e., $\{x:a<x<b\}$. Those who use this notation also write $]a,b]$ for my $(a,b]=\{x:a<x\le b\}$ and $[a,b[$ for my $[a,b)=\{x:a\le x<b\}$. Both notations are considered standard, but the $]a,b[$ notation is not common in the U.S.; I believe that it is common in France, however.

Comment: I actually think, but am not sure, that the question was rather about the fact that here the interval is $(a, a)$ (or $]a, a[$)

Comment: @servabat: You could be right; perhaps the OP will clarify.