# What does it mean when range is expressed between two "["?

Tags: calculus, notation

In this [YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WqQRQz_XYg4&t=2m24s) the presenter writes
$[0, 2^{128} [$
is this different than $[0, 2^{128} ]$
This happens around time 2:20

She also writes something that appears to be $[0, 16 [$ but there is some mark so it looks more like $[0, 16' [$ does this mean anything or was it just a scribe?

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1116898/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-notation-1-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\left[a,b\right[$ is an alternative notation for $[a,b)$. It's standard in French, for instance.

Comment: Further reading: http://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/142/why-is-american-and-french-notation-different-for-open-intervals-x-y-vs-x/193#193